# On-screen keyboard for lock screen

Tags: gnome, keyboard, software-recommendation, lock-screen, gdm

As I am having some trouble at the moment with the lock screen and entering my password, I was wondering if there was some sort of on-screen keyboard which could be displayed to me on the lock screen so that I could type in my password?

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.

Comment: What does the accessibility menu show (should look like a human figure)?

Comment: @muru: I don't see any such icon, how do I get this "accessibility menu"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Display_Manager#/media/File:GDM_Fedora_20.png You don't see the human figure icon in the top bar (first of the icons in the corner)? You are using GDM, right?

Comment: @muru: I don't see it, and yes, I am using GDM, but I have seen it before, is there some setting to turn it on?

Comment: @muru: I figured it out and posted an answer, feel free to edit and improve it if you want. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is; first you will need to activate the Universal Access Menu. To do this go to **System Settings** and select **Universal Access**:

[image: Settings menu]

Once you have done so activate the Universal Access Menu:

[image: Always show Universal Access]

After you have done that you can go into the Universal Access Menu and activate the Screen Keyboard:

[image: screen keyboard on]

And voilà, one on screen keyboard available for you to type with (this will appear if you start typing in the system somewhere, but not in a text box in Firefox or anything like that):

[image: onscreen keyboard]